# Resize uploaded image width and scale height accordingly and opposite

Tags: php

I'm working on upload script and I would like to resize uploaded image so that maximum width and height are 500 pixels.

For example, if width is greater than height, then resize width to 500 pixels, and scale height accordingly, so that original aspect ratio is preserved.
And opposite, if height is greater than width, then resize height to 500 pixels and scale width accordingly.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Try php wideimage class it is simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's ImageMagick class to do this.

You could find ImageMagick's full documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Here is a code that will resize your image to a width of 500.

```
 $image = new Imagick();

$image->readimage($filename);

$width=$image->getimagewidth();

if ($width!='500') {
                       $image->resizeImage('500', '0' ,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
       }
$image->writeImage($filename);
```

The zero in resizeImage('500', '0' ,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1); indicates that you will scale your height accordingly.  You should look at ImageMagick's documentation, it provides cool stuff to play with images.